# Spring AMQP: Register BlockedListener to Connection

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am trying to implement Blocked Listeners to RabbitMQ using RabbitTemplate of Spring AMQP. In my code i am using Spring-amqp 1.1.3 version jar file, whereas i have looked into the version 1.3.1 as well and this is unsupported in this version also. Does anyone know if i am missing any version which has support of registering Blocked listeners to the new connections in RabbitMQ. Or if is there any future release of spring amqp to support this feature.

Example Code:

```
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    connection.addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {
     @Override
     public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Connection is Unblocked");
     }

     @Override
     public void handleBlocked(String arg0) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Connection Blocked");
     }           



    });
    com.rabbitmq.client.Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

Answer (score 10):

This is not currently available out of the box; please feel free to open an [Improvement JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

However, you can add a Spring AMQP `ConnectionListener` to the `CachingConnectionFactory`...

```
connectionFactory.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel(false);
        channel.getConnection().addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {

            @Override
            public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            public void handleBlocked(String reason) throws IOException {

            }
        });
        try {
            channel.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(Connection connection) {

    }

});
```

It will be called even if the connection has already been established when you add the listener.

Comment: I have added this to get the blocked connection notification, and its working, Is there is any way to find the RabbitMQ connection close due to RabbitMQ restart @Gary Russell

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions in comments; always ask a new question. It's not clear what you are asking; there is an `onClose` method. In 2.0 there is also an `onShutDown` when a connection is forced closed.

Comment: Thank you! why is `channel.close()` invoked here? does this implementation override the way Connections/Channels are to be used to communicate with RabbitMQ? or is it a merely a hook to listen to connection blocked events?

Comment: It's just a hook. The `Connection` argument passed to `onCreate` is not the actual connection but a wrapper; the `channel.getConnection()` gives us access to the real connection so we can add the listener. The `close()` doesn't actually close the channel, it returns it to a cache for use by a future operation.

Comment: However, this is no longer needed ([since version 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/commit/b3063dc8f1e74fd248f3d4048d939b5ed762ceef)). You can now add a `BlockedListener` directly to the onCreate Connection argument. We also publish events, which can be captured by a Spring `ApplicationListener`.

Comment: thank you again! until we move to 2.x, we'll have to stick with this, which is good enough