# spring rabbitMQ blocking handler

Tags: spring-amqp

I am facing problems when resource limits are reached with rabbitMQ  , I saw the post 
[Spring AMQP: Register BlockedListener to Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105142/spring-amqp-register-blockedlistener-to-connection)
There was a suggestion for a Jira issue  , any improvement in this direction ?
especially it would have been nice if I can configure a blocking handler from XML side also.

Is there any way before a send I can check the channel status ( blocking ) since  I get into an infinite blocked state if I send on a blocking channel since no timeout is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. There is no JIRA, so no support for that feature out-of-the-box. All you need to do is that workaround provided by Gary.

It is indeed isn't possible to configure `BlockedListener` via XML configuration, but that isn't too hard to enhance the `connectionFactory` after injection to some your bean via provided hook.

We will be appreciate if you raise a JIRA and provide the feedback how that should work from the Framework perspective.