# Spring amqp is not raising timeout exception when the connection is blocked by RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

When RabbitMQ disk usage or memory usage reaches the higher threshold RabbitMQ will block connection

In the spring amqp whenever rabbitMQ blocks the connection there is no error message about the connection failure

is there is any way to set timeout for a publish in spring amqp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking connection listener is not enabled in Spring amqp by default, we need to add Blocked connection listener to the rabbitmq connection factory bean for getting blocked connection notification.

Following code will works :

```
connectionFactory.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel(false);
        channel.getConnection().addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {
            @Override
            public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            public void handleBlocked(String reason) throws IOException {

            }
        });

        try {
            channel.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(Connection connection) {

    }

});
```

Reference

1. https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html
2. [Spring AMQP: Register BlockedListener to Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105142/spring-amqp-register-blockedlistener-to-connection)